# Botão para exibir e/ou esconder teclado

Tags: java, android

Um `EditText` numérico irá receber entrada por teclado externo, então exibir o teclado padrão, deve ser opcional.

**Como faço para:**

Ao clicar no `EditText` para posicionar o cursor, o teclado não abrir ?

Abrir/fechar o teclado, com um botão separado ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Utilizei da seguinte forma:

**Exibir/Ocultar na mesma função** (`toggleSoftInput`):

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(this.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    imm.toggleSoftInput(0, 0);
```

**Somente ocultar** (`hideSoftInputFromWindow`):

```
InputMethodManager inputManager = (InputMethodManager) this.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        inputManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);
```

**Somente exibir** (`showSoftInput`):

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(this.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imm.showSoftInput(this.cod, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
etNumerico.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL);
```

Tenta do jeito acima para definir que ele não vai chamar o teclado virtual.
E para mostrar ou esconder o teclado por um botão assim:

```
//Mostrar e esconder
 private void funcaoTeclado() {
    View v = getActivity().getCurrentFocus();

    if (v != null) {

        InputMethodManager inputManager = (InputMethodManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);

        inputManager.toggleSoftInputFromWindow(v.getWindowToken(), InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, InputMethodManager.RESULT_UNCHANGED_SHOWN);
    }
}
```

Estou usando getActivity pois estou usando em um fragmento, então essa parte do código pode mudar de acordo com o contexto do seu app

Comment: Não funcionou Anderson. Mas consegui aqui já. Obrigado !

Comment: Anderson, testei novamente. Não abrir o teclado está funcionando perfeitamente. O que não funciona é mostrar o teclado. Se puder verificar, agradeço.

Comment: vou editar a resposta, acabei de testar android 8.1.0 e pegou. Faz o teste do novo jeito e me fala

Comment: Agora você alterou para método "toggle"... ficou praticamente igual ao meu ! rs  Na verdade eu testei o seu, funcionou, mas deu um problema porque o `etNumerico.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL);` ele quebrou o meu parâmetro do campo ser "number". Eu vou postar na minha resposta detalhado como ficou

Comment: Sim, a unica diferença é que já passa as flags de mostrar e esconder. O método que passei antes, eu uso numa aplicação de um tablet android 2.3, então pode ser o motivo de não pegar nos mais novos android. Acredito que o toggle seja melhor.

Comment: No meu caso sim, eu preciso do toggle porque estou usando um floating button. Mas obrigado pela mão ! ;]